# What is an Equal Word™?

Tags: word, pattern

I have a set of words. If those words follow a certain rule, they become an ***Equal Word™***. Use these examples to find out the rule for an equal word.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Equal }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\ \def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words }^™\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2017.02.04}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{ MAN }&\text{ CLEAR }\\ \hline
\text{ BALANCED }&\text{ WAVE }\\ \hline
\text{ ORDER }&\text{ HIDE }\\ \hline
\text{ FINE }&\text{ DJINN }\\ \hline
\text{ EQUALS }&\text{ LINEAR }\\ \hline
\text{ STAND }&\text{ STAIN }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rule here is

> The sum of the positions of each letter in the alphabet should be an even number.
>  
> For example: 
>  MAN: 13 + 1 + 14 = 28 
>  STAND: 19 + 20 + 1 + 14 + 4 = 58 
>  BALANCED: 2 + 1 + 12 + 1 + 14 + 3 + 5 + 4 = 42 
>  
>  The other words end up to an odd total: 
>  CLEAR: 3 + 12 + 5 + 1 + 18 = 39 
>  WAVE: 23 + 1 + 22 + 5 = 51 
>  STAIN: 19 + 20 + 1 + 9 + 14 = 63

Comment: Hm. If so, HIDE and EQUALS should swap sides.

Comment: ah yes you're right

Comment: Even with the typo you got it correct! Well done!